# should I have this logic in a view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and am not sure if the logic I have in my view model is appropriate. Here is a sample model view:

```
class ViewModel {
    public string prop1 {get; set;}
    public string prop2 {get; set;}
    List<string> prop3 {get; set;}
        ..........  // more properties


    public ViewModel() {
        prop1 = DataModel.field1
        prop2 = DataModel.field2;

        prop3 = UtilityClass.complexFunction();
       ......
    }
}
```

The problem is my view model has a lot of properties, and I thought of initializing them in a controller, but it seems cleaner to encapsulate the populating of properties within the view model to keep the controller leaner. If I should be doing this in the controller, what is the rationale for that? I'm thinking that approach would be something like:

```
ViewModel model = new ViewModel() {prop1 = DataModel.prop, prop3 = UtilityClass.complexFunction()}
```

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question, but you should avoid polluting models with behavior because it generally makes those models more difficult to share.  For example, you might think of adding some logic that can only be applied on the server to your model class; but if you want to share that model class with the client, the behavior becomes unworkable.  The purpose of the controller is to define behavior, and that of the model, data.  Provides nice encapsulation.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So would you recommend something like my latter code that has the controller passing parameters to the view model?

Answer (score 1):

The controller should instantiate the ViewModel object like you were thinking:

```
ViewModel model = new ViewModel() {prop1 = DataModel.prop, prop3 = UtilityClass.complexFunction()};
```

By doing so, the ViewModel class now is no coupled to the class *DataModel* and *UtilityClass* like in your other approach.  The ViewModel class can now work in isolation without having the needs to know anything about or depending on DataModel or UtilityClass.  This helps the ViewModel class being more easily testable.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not correct to declare those properties in Controller.

As you are using MVC. You should have 3 different layers.
So your code should be divided in to Model

```
  class Model
  {
   public string prop1 {get; set;}
   public string prop2 {get; set;}
   List<string> prop3 {get; set;}
   // more properties
  }
```

Controller should only be responsible to tie your View and Model

```
class ViewModel 
{
  //Use Instance of Model in here
  public ViewModel() // OR pass model as dependency injection 
                     //so that you can use it for Unit Testing 
  {
    prop1 = DataModel.field1
    prop2 = DataModel.field2;

    prop3 = UtilityClass.complexFunction();
    ......
    //Do not put this Conversion of DataModel to Model assignment logic in 
    //View Model's constructor write mapper file or something to convert Data Model to Model   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about an inheritance model?

```
public class ModelAddress
{
    public String Line1 { get; set; }
    public String Line2 { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String State { get; set; }
    public String Zip { get; set; }

}

public class ViewModelAddress : ModelAddress
{
    public WhizzyWhig WW { get; set; }
    public FancyWhatzitUIProperty FwUp { get; set; }

    public ViewModelAddress(ModelAddress copy)
    {
        this.Line1 = copy.Line1;
        this.Line2 = copy.Line2;
        this.City = copy.City;
        this.State = copy.State;
        this.Zip = copy.Zip;
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewModelAddress is not a logical subtype of ModelAddress, and in this case it doesnt solve anything, but inheritance does add complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Typically model is used in creating database classes (data models) with entity framework which is used to generate tables in database.

By model in asp.net mvc View we mean which class ( view model) we are going to bind with. This can be that same data model  class to behave like view model , if nothing new functions are going to add for that view to parse etc data ,  else other view model can be created to bind with view.
All the things getting from database is used in model while in view model you can parse that data or do something to bind with the view.

Following is the way to used these two models.

```
class Student {
            //DataModel
}

class StudentViewModel{
  public Student stu = null;

  public StudentViewModel(Student s){this.stu = s;}

  public void DoParseOrSomeFuntionHere(){}
}
```